# Impala Show Tables

Tags: sql, show, impala

I know in Impala (and other databases) I can run both of the following:

`SHOW DATABASES`

`SHOW TABLES`

I also know I can add optional `LIKE` or `IN` arguments e.g. to show me all the tables in database **Bananas** I could write:

`SHOW TABLES IN Bananas`

What I really want to know is a way of returning all the tables in the databases without having to recurse through (also showing database name and table name in separate fields.

I'll be running this via impala shell so I'd have to first return back all the database names and then produce a script line per database to give me the tables.

It's not a problem to do this as such, I just can't help wondering there must be a better way to end up with:

[image: DB_Tables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not yet. Impala will eventually support this by exposing tables for schema metadata (e.g. [ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)), and [IMPALA-1761](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1761) tracks that feature request.